# how to customly make exception for save method in laravel

Tags: laravel

I've been asking this question many times. I lost the count. Please, just do your best because I've been struggling for a while.

We all know laravel's save(), create(), delete() and other methods. I want to use these methods. I have some questions.

1) if I use save() method, I don't want to check if it returns true or false. because YOu'll agree with me that those if else statements everywhere sucks. so What I do prefer to do is to use try catch, but to use try catch, save() method has to throw exception. But as I found out sometimes it doesn't throw exception at all, but returns false. So I am left with checking all the time if it returns true or false?

2) I was thinking about the above problem. The fix that came my mind was that I can create a base model class(my own) and all the models will extend this class and in this class, I will override those methods that live in laravel's Model class. In that overriden methods, if it returns false, I will throw the exception. This way all is good, but still problem comes. I'll explain why.

I'm using Role-Permission package called zizaco/entrust. What really happens is Role, Permission (when using zizaco) must extend some other class which leads me to a problem where Role won't be able to extend my base model class which I mentioned. (because class can't extend two classes at the same time). Also I though of doing the trait instead of base model class. but the thing is zizaco/entrust is using trait also. in that trait, zizaco has those eloquent methods. what really happens at the end of the day is that Role has two traits , and those traits both have delete, save methods which gives me collision.

PLease I need some better way. The thing I want to achieve is the following.

I want to use save() delete() create methods in my application and I never want to check if those methods return true or false. I want them to throw exceptions no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `saveOrFail` method? It wraps the `save` method call in a transaction ([see implementation here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L677)).

There's also the age-old discussion about when exceptions should be used or what constitutes an exceptional situation. Argument could be made for only throwing an exception only in situations i.e. networking issues.

The package you described is another age-old issue of when composition works better than inhertance. That aside you could probably still have your trait and levarage [trait aliasing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php#language.oop5.traits.conflict) when `use`ing it. Would that be readable for other developers you might work with or easy-to-debug in the future is another thing.

Comment: I don't get it. most of the time, I use transactions by myself. So I HAVE My try catch and my db:beginTransaction(), if I put saveorFail in there, then what happens is i have transaction in another transaction. that does seem scary.

Comment: and saveOrFail still returns boolean or throws exception. so I will need to check again if it returned true or false.

Comment: True that, I've missed that return part. Then I'm out of ideas, except maybe using short ternaries whenever you call save, but that would mean repetition and possibility of inconsistent behaviour whenever you'd forget to check it.

Comment: exactly. I'm out of ideas too. It's getting a huge project, so I don't want to write checking all the time. I don't know what to do.